# How can I do automatic retry after a delay in MassTransit (a.k.a retry cycles, second level retries)

Tags: c#, masstransit

I'm setting up a message queue where consumption of the message may occasionally fail for a while (due to, e.g., network downtime) and in this case I'd like to retry after some time has passed.

This is available in MSMQ's WCF binding under the name [retry cycles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731380%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and in NServiceBus under the name [second-level retries](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/second-level-retries). Is something similar available in MassTransit?

I haven't been able to find an answer to this in the MassTransit documentation. The closest thing to an answer I could find on the forum was in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/masstransit-discuss/retry/masstransit-discuss/jiSbB63BZ6M/aw6hZs6nJwMJ) which suggests the answer is no but offers some workarounds mostly involving blocking the consuming thread for some period of time. I'd rather have an implementation more like the two I referenced above that continues to process other messages until the retry delay has elapsed.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there's a built-in way to handle this in MassTransit.

Let's consider your motivation for wanting to do a retry. You mention network downtime. This makes a lot of sense and is a good reason to inject some kind of delay before retrying a message again.

Given that case, however, wouldn't it stand to reason that if there is some kind of network downtime, that the same network downtime would affect the other messages in the queue? So, in fact, blocking the consumer thread isn't actually a problem. None of the messages are going to be successful, so let's just wait for a bit and try again later.

That's given the assumption that all the messages on your queue are pretty much doing the same thing (e.g. they're all generating some data that's being saved to a database server that's down).

If, however, there are many different message types in your queue, then I can definitely see why you wouldn't want to block processing of these other messages. Perhaps this would be a good time to take a look at the architecture of your consumers and see if splitting them up into multiple, purpose-built queues would make sense.

Comment: And when using RabbitMQ, you could also put a retry policy between your code and the consumer to try while the message is still being delivered, doing multiple attempts in your consumer instead of counting on MT to do it for you. Blocking helps keep RabbitMQ from cycling the entire message queue on failure as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify it at the bus level by [UseRetry](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/retries.html):

```
MassTransit.Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
{
  // ...
  cfg.UseRetry(retryConfig => retryConfig.Interval(2, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)));
  // ...
}
```